# Security issues , Making social media profile pictures secure

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, google-signin

In Facebook API, when we fetch user information we can get profile picture.

The URL is like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{some_app_user_fb_id}/....
```

Using this URL, anyone can get the facebook id of the user and can get the facebook account of the user.

**My question** : Is there any way to make the profile picture URL secure in facebook API or something where no one can make out the original account of the facebook without uploading the profile picture to some other place ?

Similarly I want to ask about google plus profile picture.
The URL is something like this:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/{some id}/{something here}/{something}/{somethingelse}/s11-c/photo.jpg
```

Google picture seems to be more secure, and I don't think anyone can access the main google plus account or gmail email using this picture URL.

**2nd Question:** So is google plus profile secure ?

Comment: Why would you need this? In what context would you need to show profile pictures of Facebook users to someone, without also letting them know who those people are at the same time?

Comment: In the web app, I want to show list of users, I have a web app where people can make scores in the game, and then the list needs to be displayed with list of scores, in that list profile picture and name is displayed. That list has to be public so I don't want people to copy image URL and figure out the facebook ID.